# Inline assembly, error: operand size conflict

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

I'm trying to write some simple asm code for practice but I get this error: error C2443: operand size conflict

I only want to add 2 numbers and then move the result to another variable.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

        int a = 3, b = 3, c;

        __asm {
            mov ax, a;
            mov bx, b;
            add ax, bx;
            mov c, ax;
        }

        printf("%d", c);

    }
```

Comment: what c++ compiler do you use and on what platform?

Comment: THe MSVC compiler is smart enough to realize that you defined a, b, c as integers which are 32-bits on that platform. So it thinks moving a 32-bit value into a 16-bit register is a conflict. You can define a,b,c as a `short int` (which is 16-bits) instead of `int`; Use 32-bit registers EAX, EBX instead of AX, BX; Or override the size with `word ptr` like  `mov ax, word ptr a`

Comment: The down side to overriding the sizes would be that the signedness of the values would potentially be lost and adding two numbers could wrap at 16-bits yielding results you may not expect when compared with 32-bit integers.

Comment: @Scheff Why do you think it's C?

Comment: @O'Niel Because, in C++, I would use `#include <cstdio>` and `std::printf()` or, even better, `#include <iostream>` and `std::cout`. (Please, note that I didn't state that it wouldn't compile in a C++ compiler as is.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff: If you compile it as C++, it *is* C++.  The fact that it might also be a valid C program is sometimes convenient, but doesn't mean it's not C++.  It might not be idiomatic or good C++ style, but it's definitely C++ when compiled that way.  The implications include that `int main()` is the same as `int main(void)` in C++, but not in C (where `main()` leaves the function signature unspecified).  If the OP was using C99 VLAs that only some C++ compilers (not including MSVC) provide as an extension you'd have a better argument that it was mistagged.

Comment: @Michal Walrnciak Visual Studio

Comment: @PeterCordes My original comment was _It looks like C._ and whether it was mistagged. Later the OP added tags for the compiler (onto request) and I was asked why I had concerns... (Oh, I'm afraid this might become even more complicated...)

Comment: @Scheff: Looks like it was MichaelPetch who added those tags, based on the MSVC-only `__asm{}` syntax being used and the MSVC-style error message.  (Technically `clang -fasm-blocks` could compile this, but it might not do magic operand-size checking and certainly wouldn't say error C2443).  Anyway, it's sorted out now, but in general if the OP tags it C++ I'm going to believe them that they're compiling their code as C++ unless compiler error messages prove otherwise.  You might say that they *should* compile as C if they'd rather be writing C, but that's a different point.

Comment: @PeterCordes I added the tag [msvc] (which is synonymous with tag [visual-c++] on SO) because I know that error `C2443: operand size conflict` is specifically a Microsoft Compiler error. I didn't base my tagging on the code. If it was just the code I wouldn't have tagged and would have asked the OP for more info.